# How to define a system account under which a windows service must run

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a windows service that just does not want to connect to my SQL database. The configured `connectionstring` App.config property specifies `Integrated Security = true`, but still the service responds with: `Unable to establish a connection to the datasource`. From what I've heard is that the service needs to be installed together with the user account which it will utilize to connect?

If so, how, when, where please!

Comment: The service could be... 1) programmatically providing a username/password combination... 2) utilizing the existing logon's credentials across the connection via the service.. it really all depends on how your database is setup, and how the service runs.  However, with the minute detail here (no code, no database details as to authentication requirements, etc.) this question is way too broad.

Comment: The account the service is running as needs to have a login to the database. As you don't want to grant logins to LocalSystem, NetworkService etc, then it's best to use a specific user account for the service, and assign that to the appropriate role(s) on the DB server.

Comment: Agreed, and there is a user account that has got adequate permissions and access to SQL Server. This same account is used for the REST API part of the project and there are no hassles there. My question is how to specify that specific account when installing the service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in order to achieve this, open the `Services Manager`, right-click on the service you want to authenticate, select the `Log On` tab and specify the account required.